# Unable to store JSON in a variable

Tags: json, node.js, async.js

I'm unable to store JSON in a variable. The json variable itself prints out when I call the getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper function but outside the variable does not store anything. How do I properly store the JSON variable in matchParticipantData.specificParticipantData?

```
function getIndividualMatchJSONObj(matchData) {
   var matchParticipantData = {
        specificParticipantData: [numberOfGames]
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++) {
       getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(matchData, matchParticipantData, i, function(err, json) {
            matchParticipantData.specificParticipantData[i] = json;
   });
} 
    return matchParticipantData;

}

function getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(matchData, matchParticipantData, indexIter, callback) {
    var individualMatchURL = 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matches/' + matchData.matchID[indexIter] + '?api_key=' + API_KEY;
    var jsonFinal;
     async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            request(individualMatchURL, function (err, response, body) {
                if (err)
                    return callback(err);
                if (response.statusCode != 200)
                    return callback(new Error('Status code was ' + response.statusCode));
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    if (matchData.championID[indexIter] == json['participants'][j].championId) {
                        return callback(null, json['participants'][j]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
], callback);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getIndividualMatchJSONObj

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfGames; i++) {
       getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(matchData, matchParticipantData, i, function(err, json) {
            matchParticipantData.specificParticipantData[i] = json;
       });
} 
return matchParticipantData;
```

The setting of json to your object is happening asynchronously, so your json is being received and set after returning matchParticipantData.

You need to somehow stall your return until the json function finishes or convert the function to use callbacks to handle/use data instead of returning data.

Normal:

```
function test() {
    return "test";
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = test();
console.log(data);
```

Callbacks:

```
function test(callback) {
    callback("test");
}
```

Usage:

```
test(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```